# How do I unblock stripe from my GoDaddy domain's firewall?

Tags: javascript, networking, dns, stripe-payments, webhooks

**Context**

I've built and deployed a javascript app using Heroku that has a Stripe integration for subscription payments. My domain is hosted by GoDaddy but the SSL and app are hosted on Heroku -- only the domain DNS and my domain redirect sit on GoDaddy.

**Problem**

The stripe webhook works in my test environment but is giving me `ERR Timed out connecting to remote host` in production and I believe it's because the DNS routing in GoDaddy fire-walling the webhook traffic (Heroku doesn't firewall and the Stripe API call from my app works so the secret keys are properly configured).

**Question**

How do I add [stripe's web or IP addresses](https://stripe.com/docs/ips) to my GoDaddy allow list so the firewall permits inbound traffic from the Stripe webhook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was user error on my part. I had incorrectly directed the user to `https://mywebsite.com` instead of `http://www.mywebsite.com` in my code.

Once I changed the code the networking issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Im in the same situation, they say, upgrade your account...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @mrdennis - I was able to figure out a solution and just posted above. Hopefully it helps your situation.